# Oracle query: if column A is null then condition on column B

Tags: sql, oracle, if-statement, null, case

I have a table

```
num1 num2  info1    info2   status1     status2  flag
14   11111 affsd    sdf     10          -        1
135  22222 fds      -       20          10       0
1513 33333 -        fds     10          30       1
21   44444 dd       a       -           20       1
-    55555 ddwd     -       10          -        0
```

Goal: to find most fitting record based on parameters and return flag.

Conditions:

1. if num is not null then match status1 to num1 and status2 to num2. If either of status is null then treat this null as "Match". i both are null then return f.e. 2;
2. if num is null:

   - match info1 to my_param_1 and info2 to my_param_2. status1 and status2 - if they exists in table then have to match to params, if they don't exists - they are null and they match.
   - if info1 and info2 is null then return f.e. 2

My actual solution is list of if-else and diffrent select in every if section, but now i wonder if this could be done in single query? Like when this column is null then condition on another. I tried something like

```
WHERE case when ... then...
```

but no luck.

I hope i explained right and everything is understood :)
Thanks!

Comment: Can you add your if-else solution for understanding requirement.

Comment: Can you clarify "match status1 to num1 and status2 to num2"? Probably you can do all of this by nesting `case` expressions.

Comment: Using a `case` statement is the right way.   What was wrong with that approach besides being unlucky?